# Acces data in a structure array

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm not understanding how i have to use pointer to structures. I'm trying with a very simple example, but it's not working.

```
typedef struct
{
char nombre [100], domicilio [200];
int codigo_postal, nro_documento;
unsigned char edad_sexo;
}
t_persona;

int main()
{
int edad;
char sexo;
t_persona* dati=malloc(sizeof(t_persona));
scanf("%d",(*dati).codigo_postal);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does my program crash? How should i put the ***int***
value in the structure?

Comment: `(*dati).codigo_postal` -> `dati->codigo_postal`.

Comment: I've already tried but it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is crashing because you are passing an uninitialized `int` to `scanf()` where it expects a pointer to `int`. I suspect you are compiling withtout warnings enabled, since you are learning I highly recommend enabling compiler warnings.

To use `scanf()` you also need to check it's return value, something like this

```
if (scanf("%d", &dati->codigo_postal) != 1)
    do_something_because_codigo_postal_is_not_initialized();
```

you must pass a pointer to your local variable to let `scanf()` be able to store the value in it, if you just pass the variable it's value will be considered an address where `scanf()` will attempt to store the result, that leads to undefined behavior, and also your variable was never initialized which is yet another cause for undefined behavior.

Also, don't use `malloc()` like that always check for it's returned value. I would rewrite all your code like this

```
typedef struct
{
    char nombre[100];
    char domicilio[200];
    int codigo_postal;
    int nro_documento;
    unsigned char edad_sexo;
} t_persona;

int main()
{
    t_persona *dati = malloc(sizeof(*dati)); // Use sizeof(*dati) which is
    if (dati == NULL)                        // far more maintainable.
        return -1; // `malloc()' failed
    if (scanf("%d", &dati->codigo_postal) != 1)
        return -1; // input error
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", dati->codigo_postal);
    free(dati);
    return 0;
}
```